# Computational complexity of higher order cumulants

Tags: st.statistics, statistical-physics

From Wikipedia:

In probability theory and statistics, the cumulants κn of a probability distribution are a set of quantities that provide an alternative to the moments of the distribution. Any two probability distributions whose moments are identical will have identical cumulants as well, and vice versa.

> The first cumulant is the mean, the second cumulant is the variance,
> and the third cumulant is the same as the third central moment. But
> fourth and higher-order cumulants are not equal to central moments. In
> some cases theoretical treatments of problems in terms of cumulants
> are simpler than those using moments. In particular, when two or more
> random variables are statistically independent, the n-th-order
> cumulant of their sum is equal to the sum of their n-th-order
> cumulants. As well, the third and higher-order cumulants of a normal
> distribution are zero, and it is the only distribution with this
> property.

There is also the concept of join cumulants described [on the same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Joint_cumulants).

Could anyone point me to a literature which discusses the computational complexity of higher order of cumulants?

Comment: Maybe not quite what you mean, but this paper extensively relies on estimating cumulants (of high order): https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00911

Comment: What kind of probability distributions do you consider? How do you represent the probability distribution as an input for the algorithm?